# Regex that starts with something and ends if a word is found, else take full line

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that starts with `--` and ends if:

- Another `--` is found (it must be included),
- Or end of line is found.

For a version with end of line it works with `--[^\n]*` or `--.*$` and for the one ending with `--` it works with `--[^\n]*--` but I can't manage to combine both so that if another `--` is found it does not take the rest of the line.

For example:

- `toto -- tata yoyo` will match `-- tata yoyo`
- `toto -- tata -- yoyo` will match `-- tata --`

Edit: according to @duDE comment, I tried with `--[^\n]*(--|.*)` but the `.*` seems to win against `--` since in second example result match is `-- tata -- yoyo`

Edit2: thanks to @guest I have the answer, and this is simply `--.*?(--|$)`

NB: by the way, I use https://www.debuggex.com/ to test regex, that I find be a great tool, and, even if for example with `--[^\n]*(--|.*)` regex and `toto -- tata -- yoyo` it returns "Don't match", we can see `-- tata -- yoyo` part matches since highlighted.

Thanks

Comment: A  "or" expression would be |. For example, ab|de would match either side of the expression.

Comment: Thanks @duDE, I updated my question with an unfortunately not successful "or" try

Comment: Does `--.*?(--|$)` work?

Comment: Thanks a lot @guest, I knew it was so simple, I didn't think about putting a `$` in the "or".

Comment: The main part to note is that `.*` is made non-greedy by adding a `?` quantifier – `.*?` will match the shortest repetition of `zero or more of anything`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @guest that commented my question I have the answer, and this is simply `--.*?(--|$)`

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/956488)

Comment: @Burgi This answer was copied from a comment that nobody posted as an answer, not from another answer.

Comment: Ah fair enough.

Comment: Yes, and this is what I put in my answer: "@guest that commented my question" :D

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your regex flavor, you can use:

**Edit:** Matches, now, the two hyphens if exist.

```
--[^-\r\n]+(?:--|$)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/N0qk7F/4)

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, as I said, I need to have the last `--` included in the result, in your demo it is not in the second line, anyway @guest answered well in my question with simply `--.*?(--|$)`.

Comment: @gluttony: See my edit, no capture group that slow down the process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like `^.*(\<|$)` (anything from start of line up to word start/end of line)...

Comment: How is this matching string beginning with `--` (2 hyphens) and ending with another 2 hyphens or end of line?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately your regex seems to match everything, and as @Toto said, how can it even match any `--` ? Anyway @guest answered well in my question with simply `--.*?(--|$)`.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the correct answer is

```
--.*?(--|$)
```

https://regex101.com/r/8mDFeE/1

With `.*?` (vs `.*`) being the non-greedy version of the pattern -- catching the **minimum** number of characters to the next match rather than the maximum.